# Почему simple_html_dom не работает с некоторыми сайтами?

Tags: php, парсер

Добрый вечер. simple_html_dom не работает с некоторыми сайтами, например world-art.ru и kinopoisk.ru, почему так?

Элементарный пример:

```
// Create DOM from URL or file
$html = file_get_html('http://www.world-art.ru/animation/animation.php?id=1');

// Find all images
foreach($html->find('img') as $element)
       echo $element->src . '<br>';

// Find all links
foreach($html->find('a') as $element)
       echo $element->href . '<br>';
```

По идее, должен вывести все картинки и ссылки с страницы. Но вместо этого - пустая страница.

Answer (score 1):

Причина, скорее всего, в коде этих сайтов. DOM- и XML-парсеры требуют валидности разметки для правильного разбора.

Comment: Жаль. Спасибо за ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Ну www.world-art.ru защищается. Сделайте

```
$html = file_get_html('http://www.world-art.ru/animation/animation.php?id=1');
print_r($html);
```

Увидите пустоту. Выход - закачивать страницы через curl эмулируя браузеры.

```
function getUrlFromCurl($url)
{
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
    $urlhtml = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    $html = str_get_html($urlhtml);
    return $html;
}
```

Только добавьте нужные опции. Ну или используйте другие парсеры, которые умеют это из коробки

Comment: Что-то не получается у меня. В первом варианте выводит какие-то массивы на секунду, потом перебрасывает сюда - http://www.world-art.ru/not_connect.html.  А  во втором варианте пустой экран.

Answer (score 1):

simple_html_dom работает только с UTF-8.
Если пихать в неё страницы в Windows-1251 - будете получать пустоту.