# Почему не получается получить данные?

Tags: php, curl

Почему эту страницу получается спарсить https://www.hltv.org/stats/teams?startDate=all&matchType=Lan
а эту не получается https://www.hltv.org/stats/teams?startDate=all&matchType=Lan&minMapCount=0
магия? Или я подтупливаю к вечеру.
Используется simple_html_dom

```
$urls2 = array('https://www.hltv.org/stats/teams?startDate=all&matchType=Lan&minMapCount=0');
//$urls2 = array('https://www.hltv.org/stats/teams?startDate=all&matchType=Lan');
foreach($urls2 as $urlsItem){ 
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $urlsItem);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        $html2 = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);

        $data2 = str_get_html($html2);
   echo $data2;
}
```

Comment: По сути страница то та же, просто фильтр

Answer (score 0):

Дело в этой строчке:

```
$data2 = str_get_html($html2);
```

До нее все хорошо, а от она как видимо работает не всегда верно.

> simple_html_dom работает только с UTF-8. Если пихать в неё страницы в
>   Windows-1251 - будете получать пустоту.
>   [Почему simple_html_dom не работает с некоторыми сайтами?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/466153/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-simple-html-dom-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D1%81-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8)

Comment: С этим все верно, забыл упомянуть что используется simple_html_dom

Comment: ну от она и работает неверно, видимо html код для нее невалидный или еще что то, нужно смотреть внутрь ее. Здесь дело не curl он все возвращает в обоих случаях

Comment: ок, спасибо, я что то про невалидный код не подумал.
буду рыть в эту сторону.
Просто странно страница то одна а когда добовляю данный фильтр &minMapCount=0 типо показать все страница приходит пустая, а если ставлю CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 0 то все нормально возвращает, магия

Comment: Проблема точно не в кодировке т.к. <meta charset="utf-8">
да и страницу без &minMapCount=0 парсит нормально, та что закоментирована